# C# pass a null value as a generic object rather than a type for overloaded methods

Tags: c#

I'm working with some legacy C# code and below are two overloaded methods that I can't change:

```
void PerformCheck(LegacyData data) {...}
void PerformCheck(object data) {...}
```

There is some code that uses the above overloaded methods.  When that code passes anything but a LegacyData reference, the `PerformCheck(object data)` gets invoked, e.g. `PerformCheck("Hello World");`  However, if null is passed, `PerformCheck(LegacyData data)` gets invoked.  Strangely the PerformCheck implementations are different depending on what is passed.  I would like the `PerformCheck(null)` to invoke the `PerformCheck(object data)` implementation instead.  How do I make this work?

Comment: Another, longer way, besides what @David_L answered is to use *Reflection* and manually invoke the method of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the behavior by casting `null` to anything other than `LegacyData`.

```
var x = new Test();
x.PerformCheck((object)null);

public class Test
{
    public void PerformCheck(LegacyData data) { Console.WriteLine("legacy"); }
    public void PerformCheck(object data) { Console.WriteLine("other"); }
}
    
public class LegacyData {}
```

This outputs "other" as expected.